# How to enable xdebug on HHVM 3.3.0?

Tags: php, debugging, ubuntu, xdebug, hhvm

I'm trying to setup remote debugging for my virtual Ubuntu 14.04.

I've enabled xdebug on my HHVM 3.3.0 by adding this to the `server.ini`:

```
hhvm.xdebug-not-done.enable=1
hhvm.xdebug-not-done.remote_enable=1
```

But it doesn't work for me. Should I perform any other moves to make it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging in HHVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454676/debugging-in-hhvm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HHVM 3.3 is no longer supported, however since HHVM 3.4 you don't need the `-not-done` in your configuration (Yes, It's stable!). For example

```
xdebug.enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9089
```

Ref: [HHVM Debugger Support on JetBrains Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18817#comment=27-865295)

Comment: @Oxwivi I found most of these in the xdebug docs, if you want it working with Eclipse, you must tweak your xdebug helper to change the IDE key to eclipse, and set that same IDE key in your Eclipse and HHVM configuration.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't let setting `idekey` without defining a proxy. I defined `enable`, `remote_enable` and `connect_back`. Since I'm running `xdebug` in a VM, I set `connect_back` as it overrides `remote_host`... except it's not working. I guess it's time to ask a new question. Thanks for the help.